# SpringJUnitConfig for mulitple junit classes

Tags: java, junit

In our project, every `Junit` class(which is annotated using `SpringJunitConfig`) is having a `@Configuration` annotated class, which creates the `Bean` which is required to test any particular Test-class method.

Example:

```
@SpringJunitConfig 
class TestClass {

  @Configuration 
  class TestConfig {
    
    @Bean 
    public TestClass testClass(DependantBean dependantBean) {
        return new TestClass(dependantBean);
    } 

    @Bean
    public DependantBean dependantBean() {
       return new DependantBean();
    }
  }

  @Autowire private TestClass testClass; 
  

  @Test
  void testMethod() { 
    //do testing
  }
}
```

However this looks handy for a single test class, but the issue is every `test class` is having its own `configuration` class, which we are trying to avoid and I wanted to have one single configuration class for my whole `test classes`. Can someone help me to remove this repeated `@Configuration`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using spring boot or the spring framework only? in spring boot you could use ```@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class })``` in your test classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create a Configuration meant only for Test cases, and it could be used in `@SpringJunitConfig`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit/jupiter/SpringJUnitConfig.html

> @SpringJUnitConfig is a composed annotation that combines
> @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) from JUnit Jupiter with
> @ContextConfiguration from the Spring TestContext Framework.

Define your TestConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationTestSpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler validationTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tpts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        tpts.setPoolSize(2);
        return tpts;
    }
}
```

---

Then using this `@SpringJunitConfig` annotation, you can actually provide the context `configuration` you need, which loads up the `Test Beans:`

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(ValidationTestSpringConfig.class)
public class HttpValidationIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

}
```